# How to hide/show fields on selecting option in openerp

Tags: openerp-7, odoo

I have a selection field and text field

```
'work': fields.selection([('tax', 'Tax Audit'), ('statutary',
'Statutary'), ('certificate', 'Certificate'), ('projection',
'Projections'), ('acount', 'Accounting'), ('others', 'Others'),
('roc', 'ROC Reg'), ('vat', 'VAT')], 'Nature Of Work'),
'details':fields.text('Details'),

<field name="work" select="0"/>
<field name="details" select="0"/>
```

**Details** field must be visible only on selection of 'roc' and 'vat'
how can I get this please help me

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```
<field name="details" attrs="{'invisible':[('work','not in',['roc','vat'])]}"/>
```